# Law of iterated logarithm for stationary sequences

Tags: probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers

Let $(X_i)_{i\in\mathbb Z}$ be a sequence of random variables which is stationary and ergodic, but not necessarily i.i.d. Does there exist a real function $f$ such that the following holds?
$$ \limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{X_1+\cdots+X_n}{f(n)}=1,\quad \text{a.s.} $$
This question is related to the [general law of iterated logarithm](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/030441499290144F). Note that $f$ might depend on the sequence of random variables. Does there exist any existence result in the non-i.i.d. case?

I need the case where $X_1\geq 0$ a.s., but $\mathbb E[X_1]=\infty$. You can also assume polynomial tail; i.e., $\mathbb P[X_1>r]\leq Cr^{-\alpha}$ for some $C$ and $\alpha$.

Comment: I think you want to say "does there exist a real function $f$ ..." before "Let $(X_i)_{i \in \mathbb{Z}}$ be ..."

Comment: @mathworker21 No, $f$ might depend on the sequence. I updated the text to be more clear.

Comment: Something like [this](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aop/1196268675)?

Comment: @user10354138 It still assumes finite variance.